# BotFramework hosting on iis

Tags: botframework

hello all i have tried to host botframework code on iis with no luck .

is there any why to host it with out using Azure or tunnling

i tried to to host it by copying files into iis

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any why to host it with out using Azure or tunnling

You can host Bot Framework bots by any means in which you would host any other web app. That could be Azure, on-prem, or whatever other means you see fit. I don't know the exact deployment steps, but Bot Framework bots do run on IIS. Local testing often uses a local IIS server.

Note that you will require an `Azure Bot` resource deployed on Azure to connect your bot to client services. You do not need to host the application itself on Azure, but you will need to point the Azure Bot resource to the endpoint of your hosted bot, wherever that is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but is there any way to not use Azure at all?

Comment: No. The Azure Bot resource is required at a minimum.